# SQS FIFO Lambda event source behaviour when MessageGroupId specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I see that SQS FIFO queues were recently [added](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-amazon-sqs-fifo-event-source/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Lambda%20now%20supports%20Amazon,modifications%20in%20the%20right%20order) as a Lambda event source.

I'm trying to understand how FIFO messages with the `MessageGroupId` parameter specified will be handled by Lambda.

From the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message_batch) SQS docs -

> Messages that belong to the same message group are processed in a FIFO manner (however, messages in different message groups might be processed out of order). To *interleave multiple ordered streams within a single queue*, use MessageGroupId values (for example, session data for multiple users). In this scenario, multiple consumers can process the queue, but the session data of each user is processed in a FIFO fashion.

The FIFO behaviour, coupled with the phrase "interleave multiple orders streams within a single queue", suggests to me that messages with a specific `MessageGroupId` will be handled by Lambda *with a concurrency of one* (ie no parallelisation because of FIFO), but that you will get concurrent Lambda execution *across* different `MessageGroupId` values.

Is this a correct interpretation ?

Answer (score 2):

After a number of experiments and talking with an AWS moderator, I concluded that this wasn't possible - you can't guarantee that an event passed to a Lambda from an SQS FIFO queue will only contain a single MessageGroupId :-(

Can't help but feel like the SQS team have missed a trick here though. If you guarantee the above then it must limit Lambda concurrency to one, in order to guarantee the FIFO principle :-(